# Passthrough not supported error in Python

Tags: python, windows, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I am trying to run a python script in cmd for analyzing large Next Gen Sequencing data files, however it crashes after writing the following error to the screen:

[8640:0124/145024.529:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(481)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

I am new to python and programing and am looking for possible reasons for this error message. I'm sure it is user error, but I am teaching myself how to use python to run this script and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have searched online for solutions or clues as to what is causing the error but am not finding responces relevant to my issue. I have tried writing --ignore-gpu-blocklist as suggested in another pos, but it was not recognized in cmd. The files run through the program are quite large and I'm a 64-bit computer, and am wondering if there is not enough GPU space for the program to execute?
Any insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Hey you can try these troubleshooting steps: check that your graphics drivers are up-to-date, check the GPU specs and make sure that it is compatible with your script,
try running the script with a smaller file (maybe you do not have enough ram)

Comment: Also please post the full error and format it with the `{}` button

Comment: If the drivers are up-to-date, it could be that the GPU does not meet the minimum requirements. What script are you trying run? What are it's dependencies? Can it be run using a CPU only?